# Bootstrap Menu bar hover color remain in parent element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I overwrite the css for Bootstrap Menu bar for mouseover in parent element. Only background color change not change in text color.

[image]

Here is my css

```
ul.nav > li:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #337AB7 !important;               
}

ul.nav li li:hover {
        text-color: white !important;
        background-color: #337AB7 !important;               
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the css property is `color: white` and not text-color

Comment: You´ve done it correctly in your first css class but wrong in your second. Instead of writing  text-color: white !important; you need to write color: white !important;

Comment: I already tested with #FFFFFF

Answer (score 1):

The property to change the text color is `color` and not text-color

```
ul.nav > li:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #337AB7 !important;               
}

ul.nav li li:hover {
        color: white !important;
        background-color: #337AB7 !important;               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the "color" of `<a>` tag inside `<li>` Like this,

```
ul.nav > li > a:hover{
    color : red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

```
ul.nav li:hover > a {
                color: #ffffff !important;
                background-color: #337AB7 !important;               
            }
```

Thanks